# Python printing Formatted text with lists nested in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, formatting

I'm in the process of writing a script that will output some system info to a text file,
I've got all the info I need but I stumbled upon one problem,

This is a part of the dict:

```
machine_info = {
    ...
    'processors': get_processors(),
    ...  
}
```

the get_processors() returns a list of all the machine's processors,

now for the problem - I want to print the processor(s) data, my printing template for now is:

```
print """...
Processor(s):\t%(processors)s
...""" % machine_info
```

obviously it doesn't really work, it prints the whole list, and I want to print it formatted,
in a way that will look like this:

```
...
Processor(s):   processor_1_info
                processor_2_info
                ...
...
```

How can I manage to do such thing?
is there a better way to format the text than using \t so it'll be more flexible?
also, is there a better way to print out the info? considering in the end it will output to a text file,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
processors_info = "\n\t\t\t".join(machine_info['processors'])
print "Processor(s):\t{}".format(processors_info)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> info = ['processor_1_info', 'processor_2_info']
>>> processors_info = "\n\t\t\t".join(info)
>>> print "Processor(s):\t{}".format(processors_info)
Processor(s):   processor_1_info
                processor_2_info
```

Another way using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
info = ['processor_1_info', 'processor_2_info', 'processor_3_info']
#info = machine_info['processors'] for your code.
print "Processor(s):{:>20s}".format(info[0])
for item in info[1:]:
    print "{:>33s}".format(item)
```

**output:**

```
Processor(s):    processor_1_info
                 processor_2_info
                 processor_3_info
```